# Backbone Marionette - Wrapping A CollectionView From Left to Right

Tags: marionette, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have a very simple Collection View working exactly as expected.  But, the underlying collection can get fairly long.  The ItemViews themselves arent very wide.  So, rather than have the Collection View run off the screen in a scrollable container, I would like to try and wrap the view from left to right maximizing the available screen width.

I have seen grid like views implemented with Composite Views, that are based on the table element.  But I am wondering if there isnt just some magical way to make Collection View wrap left to right with css?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the CSS3 'columns' properties that may be what you're looking for: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/

Comment: Man I love this site.  Thanks!